# Regex in SQLite query gives unrecognized token exception

Tags: android, regex, sqlite

I have the following query:

```
String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + DOCUMENT_TABLE + " WHERE " + DOCUMENT_TYPE + " REGEXP " + "(^|,)(pdf)(,|$)";
```

At compile time I receive this error:

> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: unrecognized token: "^" (code
>   1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM DOCUMENTTABLE WHERE
>   TYPE REGEXP (^|,)(pdf)(,|$)

The column from where clause has values written in the following format:

- doc,pdf
- pdf
- pdf,doc

How to use regex to retrieve the right information (my case, get all documents that are in pdf format, too)?

Comment: put regexp in `'expression'` (single quote).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regular expression must be in a string literal, so surround it with `'single quotes'`. This solves the syntax problem.

However, there's no `REGEXP` implementation readily in sqlite and the Android sqlite APIs don't really let you install an implementation for `REGEXP`.

To solve the underlying problem, consider redesigning your schema so that you are not storing doing queries on comma-separated values in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

You have to enclose the regex between single quotes:

```
" REGEXP " + "'(^|,)(pdf)(,|$)'";
#    here   __^         and __^
```

You could also use:

```
" REGEXP '\bpdf\b'";
```